# how to get bitmap from GLSurfaceView in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I have made a photo Effect demo. In that I am applying different effects on android.opengl.GLSurfaceView. All done successfully, but when I am going to take bitmap from that View, I got a black transparent bitmap with bitmap. I want to take only bitmap of image (not that black background).

Can anyone please help me to solve it.

**code**

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/iv_effect_img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**java code**

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot(GL10 mGL) {
    final int mWidth = mEffectView.getWidth();
    final int mHeight = mEffectView.getHeight();
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

    // Convert upside down mirror-reversed image to right-side up normal
    // image.
    for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
            ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
        }
    }

    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);

    Global.img = mBitmap;
    return mBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Better to solve grammer ,answer the query ..!!!

Comment: @ceuben-Beter to edit ,solve my problem

Comment: have you found the solution?